# SVG Mask proportions and scaling in IE11

Tags: html, svg

I'm using an SVG with a mask to create a mask effect (it needs to be working from IE11+). I have a sequence in a PNG that I use a a mask and animate the X attribute. It works fine in all browsers and the animating works in IE but the scaling of the mask it off, the proportions change. It's like it's 1/3rd of it's original width, even though the width is set.

How it should look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiM7d.jpg

How it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1YvK.png

My SVG code

```html
      <svg width="640" height="360" baseProfile="full" version="1.2">
        <defs>
          <mask id="svgMask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" transform="scale(1)">
            <image id="maskImage" width="35840" height="360" xlink:href="assets/img/mask-high.png" y="0" x="-6400"/>
          </mask>
        </defs>
        <image id="titleImage" width="640" height="360" xlink:href="assets/img/doggy.jpg" mask="url(#svgMask)" y="0" x="0"/>
      </svg>
```

Comment: The dimensions you set for the `<image>` in the mask are unusual. What are the original width and height of `mask-high.png`? Do you expect to preserve the aspect ratio, or to stretch it? - In addition, `transform` is not a valid attribute for `<mask>` elements.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yeah it's the right dimension, basically it are multiple frame which I animated to fake a CSS Mask effect. I want to it to keep aspect ratio, currently it's stretching weird (like 33% smaller) but only on IE. On other browsers it works fine. I will remove the transform, I think it serves no purpose anyway

Comment: I'd start with the assumption that you are exeeding some sort of size limit. (although I didn't find hints about that) You could test whether an image with a quarter width exposes the same problem. If not, maybe a time-delayed animation of four strips, always hiding three while the fourth runs, might work?

Comment: So I was testing the other day and it's indeed some kind of size limit, I couldn't find about it exactly so I will do some testing myself what the limit is